# How do I efficiently perform a batch processing action on almost 8,000 WordPress posts?

Tags: wordpress

I have written a WordPress plugin that analyzes a post and extracts some data from the body on save (using the `save_post` action).

My installation has almost 8,000 posts, and I need to perform this retroactively on every single post. So, I need a batch job of some kind that will iterate every post and perform this operation without timing out.

There are a number of ways to architect this, but is there a commonly accepted way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ashley Rich from [Delicious Brains](https://deliciousbrains.com/) created a Background Processing class that was designed to solve this exact problem. You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/A5hleyRich/wp-background-processing). You can also find an example of it being used inside the [WooCommerce plugin](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-background-updater.php)

Comment: I'm going to pick this as the answer because it's exactly what I was thinking of originally. However, in the end, I just ran it from the command line using some bootstrap code and will cron that.